# sending CGImageRef as an output parameter

Tags: objective-c++, cgimageref

I need to get a capture of a moving window. Because the window is moving I want to capture it in the main thread:

```
void MacRenderer::captureImageImpl(const CGRect& captureRect, const CGWindowID windowId, CGImageRef* img)
{
    *img = CGWindowListCreateImage(captureRect, kCGWindowListOptionIncludingWindow, windowId, kCGWindowImageBoundsIgnoreFraming);  //EXC_BAD_ACCESS
}

void MacRenderer::captureWindow(CGWindowID windowId, unsigned char** bgraData, int* width, int* height, int* bytesPerRow, NSRect captureRect)
{  
    CGImageRef* windowImage;

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        captureImageImpl(captureCGRect, windowId, windowImage);
    });

    //Use windowImage ...
}
```

I'm getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on the address of `img`. Why and what is the solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
void MacRenderer::captureWindow(CGWindowID windowId, unsigned char** bgraData, int* width, int* height, int* bytesPerRow, NSRect captureRect)
{  
    __block CGImageRef windowImage;

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        captureImageImpl(captureCGRect, windowId, &windowImage);
    });

    //Use windowImage ...
}
```